# What are the main stuff to put into .buildpath for ruby on rails in eclim?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, eclim

Like the title suggests, what are the main things to put into .buildpath so that when writing code in ruby on rails, source code completion, searching, and other features can work properly.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't need anything special for that. The defaults work fine as long as you're using latest Eclipse (I'm running 4.2 Juno).

I'm using [Eclim](http://eclim.org/) and after executing the "New project" command:

```
:ProjectCreate /var/www/<my-ror-project-directory>/ -n ruby
```

I have the following `.buildpath` file created:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<buildpath>
        <buildpathentry kind="src" path=""/>
        <buildpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.dltk.launching.INTERPRETER_CONTAINER"/>
</buildpath>
```

Code completion, searching work just fine.